# Why I ' cannot GET ' page in express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm new to building web apps and have been teaching myself Node Express. I have been able to get simple express apps to work on Cloud9 environments but for some reason am having trouble getting them to work with VS Code. The server runs, but pages do not get rendered at the appropriate routes. Here is my basic setup:

```
var express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  mongoose = require("mongoose");

// APP CONFIG
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/blog_app", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/blogs", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index");
});

// use port 3000 unless there exists a preconfigured port
var port = process.env.port || 5500;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("SERVER RUNNING");
});
```

My folder structure is:

```
Blog App:
-node_modules
-views/index.ejs
app.js (where this code is taken from)
package.json
```

The server runs, but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:5500/blogs I get: "Cannot GET /blogs"

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any other errors other than,  "Cannot GET /blogs"? Have a dig around in the dev tab.

Comment: It's coming back as 404 status if that's anything.

Comment: Can you share node js logs ?

Comment: does "SERVER RUNNING" get printed? If yes, check that the server listens on port 5500. app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`)).

Comment: Yes, SERVER RUNNING does get printed. When running the code you suggested I get:   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5500

Answer (score 0):

You can install `ejs`.

**For Global install:** `npm install -g ejs`

or you can **install for your projects** only: `npm install ejs`

After that, I hope it's work. I've been try it and it's working fine.

Comment: I already have EJS installed. It's showing in both node modules and package.json :S

Comment: I don't know why yours doesn't work, but I tried your code and its working fine. You can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-torvalds-5jnuw. Maybe you should restart your server or try to create another one.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be rendering the page though :S

Comment: What does the page not display? Do you mean this: codesandbox.io/s/loving-torvalds-5jnuw

Comment: It doesn't appear to be rendering the ejs file index, as I can't see the "Hello" html rendered.

Comment: It's mean you don't open this site: codesandbox.io/s/loving-torvalds-5jnuw, because there is the successfully rendered index.ejs in `blogs` path.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not familiar with codesandbox. I can see that it works, but it doesn't on vs code. Strange

Comment: If you still got some error, maybe you can try to `clean` your npm cache. From my experience, That will make it work.